# how to update off screen pivot item

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, pivot, pivotitem

I want to have a pivot with many `PivotItems`. However, doing so will impact memory. So I bind pivot to my ViewModel, which has 3 item, and pivot will generate 3 `PivotItems`.

My ViewModel is of type `ObservableCollection` and my item does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This works fine. But when I update my ViewModel, only the current `PivotItem`, and the right `PivotItem` is updated. The left `PivotItem`, which is off screen, is not updated. You can see it when you drag pivot to the left.

How to fix this? Or WP7 doesnot update off screen `PivotItem` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the main diferrences between pivot and panorama :

panorama loads all items when it loads , but pivot when you select the pivot item

Comment: thanks. But as you said, only the current pivot item is updated. Why it also update the right pivot item? Does it only update which is on the screen ?

Comment: Actually you are right , i didn't remembered that one correct , it loads and the next one (right) while user sees the current page to get better performance

Comment: It seem that pivot doesnot update what is off screen. Anyway, thanks, panorama works for me now